# Legality of relay through a scanner in the US

Tags: united-states, legal

I would like to know if it's ok to transmit amateur radio frequencies via my HT through a Bearcat police scanner to someone that has an FRS radio, and in turn they respond on their FRS radio which my HT can receive via dual band receive.

I think I, being a licensed a ham operator, can transmit on an amateur frequency which goes through the scanner to my friend, who hears it like a relay then transmits back to me on FRS frequency. We both use separate frequencies that only get connected through the scanner.  Is that illegal?

Comment: What jurisdiction?

Comment: What do you mean by "through" a Bearcat scanner? Please edit your question and add more details. As it is now, it is unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I understand this just fine. Person A has an HT, Tx on a ham freq and Rx on an FRS freq.  Person B has a scanner Rx the ham freq and Tx on FRS.  So long as person A is licensed, sure, why not.

Comment: Since you didn't specify a jurisdiction but accepted a US answer, I'm going to assume that's what you are asking about and edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the US, at least, you'd fall afoul of the rules in a few places in 97.113, "Prohibited transmissions."

97.113(a)(5)(b) says "An amateur station shall not engage in any form of broadcasting, nor may an amateur station transmit one-way communications except as specifically provided in these rules...except that communications directly related to the immediate safety of human life or the protection of property may be provided by amateur stations to broadcasters for dissemination to the public where no other means of communication is reasonably available before or at the time of the event."

Then there's 97.113(a)(5) "No amateur station shall transmit: Communications, on a regular basis, which could reasonably be furnished alternatively through other radio services." It would certainly not be hard to argue that GMRS or MURS might better suit your communications needs.

Comment: @D.Cantrell If he answered the question to your satisfaction, you can mark it as accepted (just click the checkmark next to the answer), and he can get credit for it. :-)